# Not able to obtain correct indexPath.row value from objective C file in Swift file

Tags: objective-c, swift, uitableview, row, indexpath

File: ContactsViewController.m

In this file I am using the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method to push a new View Controller to show information about the name that was pressed on the Table View Controller. The View Controller that will be displaying the information about the name is being implemented in Swift. The part that I am referring to in this code is in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, line:

```
_myIndex = indexPath.row;
```

I believe indexPath.row should return the index of the name that was tapped in the Table View Controller.

```
#import "ContactsViewController.h"
#import "Contacts-Swift.h"

@interface ContactsViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong) NSMutableArray* contacts;

@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSInteger myIndex;

@end

@implementation ContactsViewController



-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        /*NSArray *contactArray = @[@"Johnny Appleseed", @"Paul Bunyan", @"Calamity Jane"];
        _contacts = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:contactArray];*/
        /*Contact *c1 = [[Contact alloc] initWithName: @"Johnny"];
        Contact *c2 = [[Contact alloc] initWithName: @"Paul Bunyan"];
        Contact *c3 = [[Contact alloc] initWithName: @"Calamity Jane"];*/
       // _contacts = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: @[c1, c2, c3]];
        self.contacts = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self.tableView registerClass: [UITableViewCell class]
           forCellReuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.contacts.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Contact *contact = self.contacts[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = contact.name;
    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ContactsViewController *viewController = [self.navigationController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"the"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    _myIndex = indexPath.row;
}
```

File: ContactsViewController.h

This is the header file that I am using in order to have access to the objective C methods and variables when working in the swift file. (I am not very familiar with objective C so there is a strong possibility that this implementation is what is causing my problems).

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ContactsViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSInteger myIndex;

@property (nonatomic, readonly, strong) NSMutableArray* contacts;

@end
```

File: ExistingContactViewController.swift

In the ExistingContactViewController I am just trying to set the firstName label equal to the text that is present in the contacts array at indexPath.row (in the ContactsViewController.m file).

```
import UIKit

@objc class ExistingContactViewController: UIViewController {

    var contactsObject = ContactsViewController()
    @IBOutlet weak var firstName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lastName: UILabel!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("\(contactsObject.myIndex)")
        firstName.text = contactsObject.contacts[contactsObject.myIndex] as? String
    }
```

When clicking names that are added to the Table View Controller the only index that is ever printed

```
print("\(contactsObject.myIndex)")
```

is 0. Which tells me that I am not capturing the index of the name that is tapped.

[Image of myStoryboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnQ3P.png) The bottom most scene is the one that I am trying to change the First Name label to display the name of the cell that was tapped.

I have not yet been able change the title of this label when clicking on a cell. I have been able to implement this functionality when using just swift files (through watching numerous videos). I am sure that there is a key concept I am missing in the objective C files so any suggestions and/or pointers are much appreciated. If any additional details are needed let me know!

Thanks.

Comment: I believe, something is wrong with this line.`ContactsViewController *viewController = [self.navigationController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"the"];
`. Why are you creating `ContactsViewController` again when it is already being shown? I think it should be `ExistingContactViewController`

Comment: I just tried changing ContactsViewController to ExistingContactViewController with no success. The index path is still not being passed to the swift file. But the change still pushed the other view controller so it didn't do any damage either...

Answer (score 0):

Seems that in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` you are pushing a `ContactsViewController` to the navigation stack and if I understand correctly it should be instance of `ExistingContactViewController`. Also you should set the `contactsObject` property of the `ExistingContactViewController` before pushing it in the navigation stack (before `viewDidLoad` is executed) otherwise it's value will always be a new  `ContactsViewController` which, probably, is causing the issue.
I hope this helps!